# Razor default for dropdown box

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a drop down list written in Razor for a MVC app I am working on as:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BillId", "")
```

However the user does not have to select anything according to the logic of my program (the list is populated with 'Bill' objects in my controller). If they do not select any thing I get an error

`The ViewData item that has the key 'BillId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.`

How do I write a statement in Razor to return a BillId of 0 if nothing is selected?

I am not sure of the syntax as I have a background in straight java and VB but something alongs the line of

```
 If DropdownBox.SelectedIndex = 0
 Else 
 BillId = DropdownBox.SelectedIndex
 End
```

Controller as follows:

```
Function Create(id As Integer) As ViewResult
        ViewBag.id = id
        Dim job As Job = New Job
        job.CustomerId = id
        job.JobAmount = 0
        job.JobDate = Date.Now()
        job.JobStatus = "Active"

        Dim BillList = New List(Of Bill)()

        Dim BillQuery = From s In db.Bills
                        Select s

        BillList.AddRange(BillQuery)

        ViewBag.BillIdList = New SelectList(BillList, "BillId", "BillDate")

        ViewBag.BillId = New SelectList(BillList, "BillId", "BillDate")

        Return View(job)
    End Function
```

The POST function for create is as below:

```
    <HttpPost()>
    Function Create(job As Job) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.Jobs.Add(job)
            db.SaveChanges()

            Dim customer As Customer = db.Customers.Find(job.CustomerId)
            Dim customerNumber As String = customer.CustCellphone.ToString()
            Dim messageSender As SendMessage = New SendMessage
            Dim smsMessage As String = "LAUNDRY: Job Number " & job.JobId & " has been booked in. You will be notified when individual services within it are ready for collection."
            messageSender.SendMessage(smsMessage, customerNumber)

            Dim url As String = "/RequestedService/AddService/" + job.JobId.ToString()
            Return Redirect(url)
        End If
        Return View(job)
    End Function
```

**EDIT**

I was wondering too how this is passed back as in the POST I may be able to check for a 'null'? However I feel the problem may be the moment the submit button is pressed

Comment: Could you show your controller code?

Comment: Could you please Add the Actions that receives the Create in `Post`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your POST controller action you forgot to populate the ViewCrap (oops, I meant ViewBag) before returning the view:

```
<HttpPost()>
Function Create(job As Job) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        ...
    End If

    ' Here you must populate the ViewCrap before returning the view the same 
    ' way you did in your GET action because your view depend on it
    Dim BillQuery = From s In db.Bills
                    Select s
    ViewBag.BillId = New SelectList(BillQuery.ToList(), "BillId", "BillDate")

    Return View(job)
End Function
```

But I would hyper strongly recommend you to use view models and forget about the existence of the ...... (the word that I don't want to pronounce).

---

UPDATE:

Now let's look at the correct way to implement this (which is by using view models). A view model is a class that you should define for each of your views and which will represent its specific requirements. So from what you have said in the comments section to my answer you want to have a dropdown list in your view where the user has to select a bill from a dropdown and which is required.

So let's roll the view model:

```
public class JobViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a bill")]
    [Display(Name = "Bill")]
    public int? SelectedBillId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Bills 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return db.Bills.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.BillId.ToString(),
                Text = x.BillDate.ToString()
            });
        } 
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    ... here you could put any other properties that you want 
        to display on the view, things like JobId, ...
}
```

then we define our controller with the 2 actions:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    var model = new JobViewModel
    {
        CustomerId = id
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(JobViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Using AutoMapper here to map between the domain model
        // and the view model (http://automapper.org/)
        var job = Mapper.Map<JobViewModel, Job>(model);

        // Now call your service layer to do the necessary processings
        // on this job domain model including saving the job and sending 
        // messages and stuff. This avoids polluting your controller with
        // business logic code which belongs to your service layer
        ServiceLayer.ProcessJob(job);

        return RedirectToAction("AddService", "RequestedService", new { id = job.JobId });
    } 

    return View(model);
}
```

and finally you will have a corresponding view which will be strongly typed to the view model:

```
@model JobViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedBillId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedBillId, Model.Bills, "-- select --")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedBillId)
    </div>

    ... some other input fields

    <p><button type="submit">OK</button></p>
}
```

---

And now, as promised in the comments section let me show what I dubbed the absolute *pornographic* approach to solve this and which if you implemented in your application I will have to ask you to no longer come back and ask any ASP.NET MVC related question on StackOverflow :-)

The *pornographic* approach consisted into manually inserting an item with id = 0 and text = empty string into the beginning of the list and then inside the controller verifying if the selected id equals 0 in order to check whether the model is valid or not:

So in your GET action:

```
Function Create(id As Integer) As ViewResult
    ViewBag.id = id
    Dim job As Job = New Job
    job.CustomerId = id
    job.JobAmount = 0
    job.JobDate = Date.Now()
    job.JobStatus = "Active"

    Dim Bills = db.Bills.ToList().Select(Function(s) New SelectListItem With { .Value = s.BillId.ToString(), .Text = s.BillDate.ToString() })
    Bills.Insert(0, New SelectListItem With { .Value = "0", .Text = "" })
    ViewBag.BillId = Bills

    Return View(job)
End Function

<HttpPost()>
Function Create(job As Job, BillId as Integer) As ActionResult
    If BillId > 0 Then
        db.Jobs.Add(job)
        db.SaveChanges()

        Dim customer As Customer = db.Customers.Find(job.CustomerId)
        Dim customerNumber As String = customer.CustCellphone.ToString()
        Dim messageSender As SendMessage = New SendMessage
        Dim smsMessage As String = "LAUNDRY: Job Number " & job.JobId & " has been booked in. You will be notified when individual services within it are ready for collection."
        messageSender.SendMessage(smsMessage, customerNumber)

        Dim url As String = "/RequestedService/AddService/" + job.JobId.ToString()
        Return Redirect(url)
    End If
    ModelState.AddModelError("BillId", "Please select a bill")
    Return View(job)
End Function
```

and inside the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BillId")
```

Comment: But I have used similar code elsewhere and have not populated it in the <POST> because the view it returns no longer has the dropdown box in it, but these others all have the user selecting something, what I would like here is if they do not select anything (i.e. it is left as blank) that the value it saves into BillId is 0?

Comment: No, you cannot possibly have used this code as this code cannot work. Your DropDown depends on the `ViewBag.BillId` and if you attempt to render the view without putting a value inside, it will simply crash. As far as your requirement is concerned, man, you really should look and start using view models. Really, so much really.

Comment: It has definately worked as it does not return a view in real world examples, I can actually take this out, it returns the Redirect. I dont expect it not to be valid and thus it redirects to another view where this BillId is no longer necessary?

Comment: Yes, if it redirects you no longer need it, of course. That's why I put it immediately before returning the View. To avoid calling it if you are about to redirect as you don't need it in this case.

Comment: Ah perfect. Thanks. I must take it out. My sloppy coding. Would you have any idea though how I get the dropdown box to set BillId to 0 if nothing is selected? As I am getting the following error The ViewData item that has the key 'BillId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: No, you can't do this. The DropDownList helper generates an empty string for the default value. You could do an absolute pornographic code and manually insert into the begging of your list an item with value = 0 and text = empty string and then use `@Html.DropDownList("BillId")`. But if you do this, please don't come back and ask more questions here :-) So the correct way to do this is to use a view model in which the BillId property will be a nullable integer (`Nullable(Of Int32)`). Then you simply decorate this property with the `<Required>` attribute and validation will work as well.

Comment: Ah right, Ive only recently been coming to the grips with view models, is it then possible to convert this to a Job object? One other idea I have had is to add the first row of the select list as something along the lines of "No Bill" (where it's BillId = 0) but I am not sure how to implement this as it seems to take the query and convert it and doesnt allow me to add an item first? I can then just validate that the user selects an option and they can select No Bill.

Comment: Haha how ironic that in my reply I just asked how to do what you deemed 'pornographic'. Unfortunately I wouldnt know how to do this anyways as I am not sure how to manually add something to the beginning

Comment: OK, I see that you are new. I will update my answer to show you the correct way to do this. Give me a couple of minutes. But it will be C#. I hate VB.NET.

Comment: Thank you so much! My expertise is in Java and Ruby (new to rails too) and so I understand concepts but lack on the code. Could you also include your 'porno' solution just for reference as I would love to know how to manually add individual items to select lists

Comment: @NParks, yes, sure, I will include the porno solution as well. No worries.

Comment: Thank you. Will implement the View Model approach. Much appreciated.